# Help me understand decidability of an axiom system of a theory

Tags: logic, decidability

The author of the book I'm reading defined an axiom system $X$ of a theory $T$ like this:

> Let $X$ be a set of formulas. Then $X$ is an axiom system of a theory
> $T$ of which it holds that $T = \{ \alpha \in \mathcal{L}^0 : X^g \models \alpha \}$, where $X^g$ is the universal closure of $X$ and
> $\mathcal{L}^0$ is the set of sentences of the language $\mathcal{L}$.

He then goes on to define a *recursively axiomatizable theory*:

> A theory is recursively axiomatizable if its axiom system is decidable.

The problem is that there are no clear examples of decidable axiom systems given in my book (thus far). I know that a set $Z$ of strings of an alphabet $\mathsf{A}$ is decidable iff there is an algorithm which tells us after finitely many steps whether a string $\xi$ belongs to $Z$, for all strings $\xi$ which we can form from $\mathsf{A}$.

I think the essence of my problem is that I can't imagine the condition for a formula belonging to $X$ which the algorithm would be checking. I would appreciate any examples and clarifications which would make the concept more clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: An "axiom system" is a collection of fomulas; the "usual" axiomatizations of e.g. [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Classical_propositional_calculus_systems) are clearly decidable because the we can always "parse" a formula to check if it has the "logical form" of one of the *axiom schemata*: we can write a computer program (a compiler) to do it.

Comment: In the example above, the issue is: is the set $X$ of formulas decidable? If $X$ is finite the answer is obviously yes. If is infinite... it depends on the "rule" governing the membership of set $X$. If we choose as $X$ the set of **all** first-order valid formula, we have that this set is not decidable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't see how this is relevant to my question, since I assume that we already know that $X$ is a set of formulas? I was expecting that the algorithm would be checking some condition related to the theory $T$. In other words, what would be the input of an algorithm whose existence proves the decidability of $X$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If I understand you correctly, the algorithm is always checking whether a formula $\alpha$ fits the definition of a set $X$ (as given in a semi-formal metalogical set theory)?

Comment: Are you assuming that the set $X$ is finite? if so, it is obviously decidable: check if a formula is in the list. But first-order Peano arithmetic has an *infinite* number of axiom, due to Axiom schema for Induction. In this case, it is still decidable, because the axiom schema specifies a "pattern" that can be checked.

Comment: Relate: [Why is ZFC recursively axiomatizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956912/why-is-zfc-recursively-axiomatizable)

Comment: See [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing): "is the process of analyzing a string of symbols, either in natural language, computer languages or data structures, conforming to the rules of a formal grammar."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, I'm not assuming $X$ is finite. If it were, $X$ would be decidable, since it would be possible to define its elements by a big disjunction, and then the algorithm proving the decidability of $X$ would just check all of the disjunct, which would indeed be a finite procedure. Did I get this right?

Comment: And see also [Proof assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant): we have software checking if a derivation is correct. A fortiori they can check if a formula is an instance of an axiom.

Comment: Finally, see [True arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic): "defined to be the set of all sentences in the language of first-order arithmetic that are true in $\mathcal {N}$ (written $\text {Th}(\mathcal {N})$). [It] is not decidable nor recursively enumerable."

Answer (score 2):

You basically have all the ingredients:  You have a set $X$ of statements as generated by some language $L$. Now, $X$ is decidable if and only if there is an algorithm that can decide whether or not a given string, as generated by that same language $L$, is an element of $X$ or not.

Example: [Peano Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)

So here you have 6 axioms plus one axiom scheme, and it is easy to check if any given sentence is one of the 6 axioms o an instance of that axiom scheme. Thus, this is a decidable axiom set.